# Check whether connection to the database is possible or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to connect to the sql server database from my c# code.
sometimes because of some error( i dont know what it is) i cannot open connection
that is
conn.open() throws exception
so i need to check whether i can connect to the database before i am opening connection.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I think the best idea is still to find out why you get the error on the conn.open. Any other way of solving this problem is just sticking your head in the sand.

Comment: ok. thats fine.. But the problem is that my server will catch if any errors are thrown. Also the team lead says we know that here may happen exception. Then why dont you can test whether the connection can establish or not?

Comment: @ZMRBINU You "test" whether the connection can establish or not by *trying to make the connection*.

Comment: You need to test the connection by attempting to Open a connection!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test if you can make a connection is to *try to make a connection*. Catch any exceptions that are thrown, and use them to display an error or try to determine the cause. (most connection errors aren't going to be something your program can fix on the fly).

```
try{
    conn.open();
    ...//other stuff
}catch(Exception ex){
    //handle exception
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to throw any exception. Is there any way other than this?

Comment: You don't throw an exception, you catch an exception.

Comment: @ZMRBINU Any way you would try to "test" a connection that fails will probably end up throwing an exception. If you built up a raw `Socket` and tried to connect with something inaccessible, for instance, the same thing would happen. The error you got back would just be harder for you to deal with.